# Auto Suggestion list: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when the XPath expression is null

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
autosuggestionselect(By.xpath(
 Configurations.getSalesLocator("//ul/li/a[text()='"+InvestigationNo+"']")));


public void autosuggestionselect(By by) throws InterruptedException {
    List <WebElement> Elements = driver.findElements(by); 
    System.out.println(Elements.size());        

    for (WebElement element : Elements) {
        System.out.println(element.getText());
        String actual = InvestigationNo;
        String expected = element.getText();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        if (actual.equals(expected)) {
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This happens when I try to select an item from the auto suggestion list.  Please help.

Comment: How about adding the stacktrace and highlighting the line the exception is thrown from? What you mean by xpath expression is null? What is the final xpath from the Configurations.getSalesLocator method? Relevant html would be a bonus.

Comment: Configurations.getSalesLocator() returns null. Share the code of that method